# Android NavigationView : not show full item and not truncate

Tags: android-support-library, title, menuitem, navigationview

**Problem** : NavigationView *not show full text* of menu item, also *not truncate text*.

This item I see correctly - two words "*Small title*":

```
<item
android:id="@+id/example1"
android:icon="@drawable/filter_2"
android:title="Small title"
android:checked="false"
app:actionLayout="@layout/menu_counter" />
/>
```

And with next item - I see only first two words "*Small title*" without any truncate of next word "*andveryverylongword*":

```
<item
android:id="@+id/example2"
android:icon="@drawable/filter_2"
android:title="Small title andveryverylongword"
android:checked="false"
app:actionLayout="@layout/menu_counter" />
/>
```

Widget :

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
android:id="@+id/nav_view"
ndroid:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="start"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>
```

Also : AndroidStudio 1.5, support library.

**EDITED :**
Here is example of standart project "Navigation Drawer Activity" in Android Studio.

activity_main_drawer.xml :
[image: menu]

in mobile :
[image: not see long word]

Answer (score 7):

I just got this working
* Override design_navigation_item.xml and change it to use
 `android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:minHeight="?android:listPreferredItemHeightSmall"`

- Override design_navigation_menu_item.xml to use maxLines=2

Kinda cool, I can't believe that works.  Thanks to the guy on stackoverflow that talked about overriding icon size, which helped me thinking in this direction.

Comment: I have similar problem described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36157300/how-to-set-ellipsize-in-menu-item-of-navigationview. Could you provide more information about overriding design_navigation_menu_item.xml?

Comment: @AleksanderMielczarek Basically just copy and paste the code from file:/usr/local/google/buildbot/src/googleplex-android/mnc-supportlib-release/frameworks/support/design/res/layout/design_navigation_menu_item.xml into a new design_navigation_menu_item.xml you make in your  /rest/layout directory and then modify the things you need.  Spelunk the source code as needed to see if you need to override subheader or any of the rest. I still haven't figured out the compound drawable yet, if it can be lined up to the left top like a bullet point instead of the center.

Answer (score 5):

Add `app:itemMaxLines="2"` in NavigationView of your layout.
That worked for me.

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            app:itemMaxLines="2"
            android:background="@color/background_color"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```