# How to set ellipsize in menu item of NavigationView?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, menuitem

I want set android:ellipsize="end" in menu items of NavigationView. In my current implementaion when text in menu item is too long, it's just cut at the end. Here is what I've tried so far:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        app:itemTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme.Widget.NavigationView.TextAppearance"
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        style="@style/AppTheme.Widget.NavigationView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"/>

<style name="AppTheme.Widget.NavigationView" parent="Widget.Design.NavigationView">
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/AppTheme.Widget.NavigationView.TextAppearance</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/drawer_background</item>
        <item name="itemTextColor">@color/color_drawer_item</item>
        <item name="itemIconTint">@color/color_drawer_item</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Widget.NavigationView.TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
        <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
</style>
```

**Edit:**

Another possible solution is described here: [Android NavigationView : not show full item and not truncate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35600267/android-navigationview-not-show-full-item-and-not-truncate/35952683#comment59998866_35952683)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add a new style to the *styles.xml*:

*res / values / styles.xml*

```
<style name="TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
</style>
```

Set the new style to the `NavigationView`:

*res / layout / activity_main.xml*

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
    app:theme="@style/TextAppearance" />
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 parts to this questions - ellipsize long names and maxLines for very long names.
As mentioned in another answer, ellipsize is straightforward. Create a style:

```
 <style name="NavigationMenuItemTextAppearance">
    <item name="android:ellipsize">end</item>
</style>
```

Add this style to your NavigationView:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_drawer_header"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_nav_drawer"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
    app:theme="@style/NavigationMenuItemTextAppearance">
</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

To set the number of lines you'd allow the name to show for, it can be done by over-riding the layout file: design_navigation_menu_item.xml. Although as per Material design guidelines, only 1 line is allowed for very long menu option [material design navigation drawer](https://material.io/components/navigation-drawer/#anatomy)

Just copy the support library's into your own design_navigation_menu_item.xml and place in the layout folder. Change maxLines="2"

```
 <CheckedTextView
    android:id="@+id/design_menu_item_text"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/design_navigation_icon_padding"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"/>
```